# Extracting fields from path and adding them to new elapsed events

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have files stored as follows:
c: /..../ agency / device / log.txt
I want to extract the fields of agency and the device and add them to each event in the log.
Now I'm doing this using a grok filter, and it does work well for all the events in the log, but I want these fields to be added to new elapsed events created, and I'm necessarily interested in creating a new event.
This is how my log looks right now:

```
filter
{
    grok {
        match => {path => "%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:agency}/ {GREEDYDATA:device}/%{GREEDYDATA}.txt"}
    }
    elapsed{
        start_tag => "a"
        end_tag => "b"
        unique_id_field => "host"
        timeout => 100000
        new_event_on_match => true
        add_tag => "ab"
        keep_start_event=>last
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your issue? the grok parsing is not always working, or you don't get the new elapsed events? Generally speaking, you better replace the GREEDYDATA with more accurate/specific regex, in order to be more efficient and have better matches

Comment: the issue is that the grok filter work only on events that have a path, meaning just on the original log events.
The events created in the elapsed filter do not have links to the events on the log (for that matter, their date is also different), so they have no path.
Now the agency and device only appear in the path, and only events with path can generate these fields. I would like to create a kind of global variable that will keep these fields and so I can set them to the new events as well.

Comment: you can use the unique_id_field in order to provide a more granular transaction id (`host` is too wide), then you can use that id for filtering the relevant events, and add some filters/aggs for the path in order to group events. you can add a second agg like top_hits to display different fields values

Comment: good idea, thank you!